# Java - Scanner using while(in.hasNext())

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

So I have the following where d is a string of text:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(d);
```

Then I use this in a while loop like:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {

function(*********);

}
```

However, I want to pass each word to the function method. Initially I (rather foolishly) tried ti send in.hasNext(), knowing full well it was a boolean! But my question is how to I find the current word the while loop sees as the next word so I can use it in methods?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html - `next()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has examples on how to use the `Scanner` in a loop like this.  You can use

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    function(in.next());
}
```

Comment: If I call this twice though such as function(in.next()) and function2(in.next()), will the second method use the NEXT different word in the text string?

Comment: Yes it will.  But you can save a reference to it in a local variable.  String next = in.next(); f1(next); f2(next);

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method.  It returns a `String`.

Assuming you have not changed the default delimiter (whitespace) via `useDelimiter(...)`, this should break up your text into the words (and numbers) that compromise it.